# Leaflet map not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, leaflet

I have been trying to add a Leaflet map to my web page but it isn't rendering correctly.  When I load the page it just shows as a grey box and I can't see anything until I start to zoom out. It's probably something basic I am missing that I can't spot for looking.

I added in the coordinates long, lat for New Zealand but it didn't work, so I reversed the order to lat, long as someone else suggested and that didn't work either.  I also added a marker to test where that would show, it should be on Wellington New Zealand but it seems to be showing up somewhere in the middle of the ocean.  I also am unsure what zoom I should be using I have tried all sorts of different numbers but it always looks the same, nothing there until I zoom right out and then it's miles off my target of New Zealand.

JS:

```
// initialize the map on the "map" div with a given center and zoom
var mymap = L.map('mapContainer').setView([40.9006, 174.8860], 5);

var Esri_WorldGrayCanvas = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
    attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(mymap);

var marker = L.marker([41.2784, 174.7767]).addTo(mymap)
.bindPopup('The Beehive Wellington, house of Parliament')
```

HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <!--CSS STYLE SHEET REFERENCE-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ass
```

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.emailjs.com/sdk/2.3.2/email.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
        emailjs.init("user_6IJi6iUGTMBKBwowkfsSh");
        })();
    </script>
    <script src="assets/js/sendEmail.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

```
<!--START OF MAP-->
        <div class="mymap col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <!--START OF DROPDOWN-->
            <div class="search-options">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <select class="select-box">
                        <option>North Island</option>
                        <option>South Island</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="radio-buttons">
                    <form>
                        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="option" value="track" checked> Track<br>
                        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="option" value="Hut"> Hut<br>
                        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="option" value="Campsite"> Campsite<br>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END OF DROPDOWN-->
            <!--START OF LEAFLET MAP-->
            <div id="mapContainer"></div>
            <!--END OF LEAFLET MAP-->
        </div>
```

I expected to see a map of New Zealand by itself when the page rendered and a marker on Wellington at the bottom of the North Island.  When it does render, it's so far zoomed in I can't see a thing and I have to zoom way out, but then it's no where near New Zealand and the marker for Wellington is at the top of the pacific ocean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong `[lat, lng]` for New Zealand as well as `Wellington`.

It should be

```
var mymap = L.map('mapContainer').setView([-40.9006, 174.8860], 5);

var marker = L.marker([-41.2784, 174.7767]).addTo(mymap)
```

Comment: Great!.  I was starting to suspect it had something to do with the South East coordinates NZ's lat long works on, if I look at the USA it's all North, West and I wasn't sure which way around I should be writing it and if it needed `-` or not.  Working now thank you :)